# PHP: how to test mailing to localhost on Linux and actually receiving it?

Tags: php, linux, email, localhost

I'm building a daemon in php that checks for received emails which it then stores in the database leading them through a whole process. The thing is that I want to build some unit tests for this, for which I don't want to setup a whole mail server.
So for tests I want to somehow send emails to localhost, which should then be picked up by the daemon and processed further. So I tried the following:

```
$headers = 'From: me@mydomain.com \r\n Reply-To: me@mydomain.com \r\n X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail('www-data@localhost', 'THE SUBJECT', 'THE BODY IS HERE', $headers);
```

When I then run `mail` from the command line, I just get a message saying `No mail for kramer65`.

So my question; does anybody know how I can send emails to localhost in php, and how I can then read these emails from within php again? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
So I figured that it is sending an email to the www-data account, and not to my personal kramer65 account. I changed the `to` email address into kramer65@localhost, and when I now run `mail` I get

```
kramer65@php0:~$ mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/kramer65": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 kramer65e@php0        Fri Apr 25 10:48   16/495   THE SUBJECT
&
```

My following question is now; how do I read or somehow get this email from within php?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you have configured the php internal mail settings. If you configured it to use a local mail forward agent (`sendmail` or similar) then you should be able to send messages to a local account (*not* a local email address) by just specifying the account name. At least this is what such agents offer. Unless php explicitly prevents such usage it might be worth a try.

You cannot send to a local email *address*, since that requires an email server, specifically an smtp server (`exim` or the like). Without it there is no component that could accept an incoming message.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I just updated my question. I was now able to send an email to kramer65@localhost and see it by running `mail` from the command line. I now want to be able to read the emails that you see by running `mail` from within php. It would be ideal if I could somehow get them as an array in php. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the `imap` extension php brings. It allows to use different protocols, besides `imap` and the outdatedd `pop` it also offers access to local mail boxes.